# Facebook connect php sdk Hide ?code=xxxxxxxx

Tags: php, facebook, sdk

I use the Facebook connect sdk php to login to me website, there is no problem to login but i just want hide ?code=xxxxxxxxxx, how can i do this ?

Thanks

Comment: Can you be more explicit or put some code ? Are you speaking about variable in URL ?

Comment: What is the code ? Why not `hash` or `encrypt`  it ?

Comment: I'm a beginer i'am using the example of facebook php sdk, how can do it ?

Comment: I'm login without problem the url returned is like ?code=XXXXXXXXXX#_=_ i just want to hide the "?code=" part

Comment: @Debflav yes i speaking about variable in URL

Comment: If you want to change the behavior of the facebook sdk you can override it (I don't know the sdk and I don't know if it's a good idea). However what is the purpose ? An hidden variable does not mean secure. For instance, you can see it in the developer tool.

Comment: @Debflav I trying HybridAuth(http://oyanix.com/opensource/hybridauth/) and it does it, i just want to understand and doing the same

Comment: When I click 'connect with Facebook' I see an user id in the URL. As @ShankarDamodaran said maybe you want to hash or encrypt the code ? But you will never hide it.

Comment: As far as you're using `code` you're fine, because **`code` can be used once (I repeat, only once)!** and if you insist on removing it you can try JS solutions out there

Comment: @Debflav delete or hide totally is impossible i know, just in URL.
In HybridAuth in URL there is only end of code (#_=_)

Comment: @AdamAzad yes i know it can be used once

Comment: You can not “hide” it, because it is essential for the login flow.